# how to print the exact date cell value in the excel sheet date format like mm/dd/yyyy using apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

I am using apache poi 3.5 for extracting data from the excel sheet.i having the date cell formatted in mm/dd/yyyy.

If i print using cell.getDateCellValue() then print the date in other format.so, i want to print the date that is in the actual format of excel sheet cell.

how i do it..Please guide me way to do it....

Saravanan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just call the method `formatCellValue(Cell)`, `formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator)` in the `DataFormatter` class. It will print the value as it is in the excel sheet.

`formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvalator)` for formula cells...